# The “acoustical signals warning you how close an object is behind you” beeps faster

Tags: singular-vs-plural

The following is taken from a CNN news article. I'm wondering if "beeps" should be changed to "beep," since the subject "signals" is plural. But then the whole subject is enclosed by quotation marks.

> It is similar to a car backing up, said Chagnaud. The “acoustical signals warning you how close an object is behind you” beeps faster the closer you are to an object, Chagnaud noted.

Comment: More likely, he should have said 'signal' in the singular. Maybe just a typo.

Comment: Is there even the word *acoustical*? Isn't it *acoustic*?

Comment: @KateBunting When a car is backing up, does it make only one signal when it's approaching an object behind?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, there is. But that's not the main issue.

Comment: One, two or many beeps, they are still *a signal*.

Comment: You have discovered the mangled English that is CNN. Go now and learn English elsewhere.

Comment: @FeliniusRex How would you revise the sentence? By replacing "signals" with "signal" or "beeps" with "beep??

Comment: @Apollyon Well if you want my input, I'd remove the quote entirely and paraphrase the speaker: *The signal warning you how close an object is beeps faster the closer you are to an object, Chagnaud noted.* I mean, they're paraphrasing him for half the quote anyways and what they're quoting is generic and not of any real interest!